# TimeoutException in edge using Feign and Hystrix

Tags: spring, netflix, netflix-eureka, netflix-zuul, netflix-feign

I'm building a training app with Netflix micro-services APIs.

This is my edge, starting on localhost:9999:

```java
@EnableHystrix
@EnableZuulProxy
@EnableEurekaClient
@SpringBootApplication
public class EdgeApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(EdgeApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

I defined the 2 following apps:

`app-a` exposes a simple web service `service-a` and starts on localhost:8081 
`app-b` exposes a web service `service-b` which calls `service-a`, and starts on localhost:8082

`service-b` calls `service-a` using Netflix Feign:

```java
@FeignClient(value = "app-a", fallback = AppAFallback.class)
public interface AppAClient {
    @RequestMapping(value = "service-a", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    List<Entity> serviceA();
}
```

```java
@Component
public class AppAFallback implements AppAClient {
    private static final Entity DEFAULT_ENTITY = new Entity();

    @Override
    public List<Entity> serviceA() {
        return Collections.singletonList(DEFAULT_ENTITY);
    }
}
```

While `app-a` and `app-b` are running, every service answers as expected:

- http://localhost:8081/service-a
- http://localhost:8082/service-b
- http://localhost:9999/app-a/service-a (through edge)
- http://localhost:9999/app-b/service-b (through edge)

The fallback `AppAFallback` should be called if `app-b` is down. However I have to wait about like 1 minute before it happens.

Just after the `app-b` is down:

- http://localhost:8081/service-a works well and the fallback is called
- http://localhost:8082/service-b is not reachable
- http://localhost:9999/app-a/service-a TIMEOUT : `HystrixRuntimeException: app-a timed-out and no fallback available.`
- http://localhost:9999/app-b/service-b TIMEOUT : `HystrixRuntimeException: app-b timed-out and no fallback available.`

And 1 minute after `app-b` is down:

- http://localhost:8081/service-a works well and the fallback is called
- http://localhost:8082/service-b is not reachable
- http://localhost:9999/app-a/service-a works well and the fallback is called
- http://localhost:9999/app-b/service-b GENERAL : load balancer does not have available server for client: `app-b`

And this is the result I expected. Any idea about why the calls to `app-a/service-a` just after `app-b` is down are giving me TIMEOUT?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I've experience the same problem, and I think (not tested), it's Eureka's updating frequency cause the problem. Just after app-b is down, Eureka still thinks app-b is up (not yet checked the heartbeat). And after app-b is down 1 minute, Eureka known app-b is down, just tells your app-a there is no app-b, thus the fallback fired immediately.